# how to create a Dockerfile for pdnsd?

Tags: docker

Is there a Dockerfile for pdnsd ? please I need it.
Or someone can explain how to create a simple docker file for pdnsd ?

thanks.

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I can has dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this image as a base for your pdnsd container: 
https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/fbiete/centos_epel_pdnsd/

You will need a Dockerfile similar to this (you don't need to change the FROM line):

```
FROM fbiete/centos_epel_pdnsd:1.2
MAINTAINER Your_Name <your_email>

COPY pdnsd.conf /etc/pdnsd.conf
```

Put in the same folder your pdnsd.conf file and build the image:

```
docker build -t <put_here_your_image_name:and_tag> .
```

Create a container using the image

```
docker run -d -p 53:53 -p 53/udp:53/udp <put_here_your_image_name:and_tag>
```

And that should be all.